# Some Record types are surprisingly considered compatible

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon this fairly simple use case in typescript:

```
type A = { 'a': number }
type B = { [x in number]: A };

let a: A = { a: 42 };
let b: B = a;
```

Type A and B seems totally unrelated, and I would expect it to fail on the last line but it doesn't. Could someone explain me why ?

Comment: That's strange, because it *does* show the expected error if you do `let b: B = { a: 42}` and allows (also as expected) `let b = [{a : 42}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be yet another case of TypeScript's missing excess property checks. Typing the variable `b` with the type `B` does not guarantee you that `b` will **only** have number-properties. It only guarantees that every number-property will have the type `A`. The type `A` actually conforms to this constraint. That's why we can assign a variable of type `A` to another one of type `B`.

```
let b1: B = {} as { a: 123, b: "abc", 0: { 'a': 1 } } // totally fine
let b2: B = {} as { a: 123, b: "abc", 0: "123" } // Error: we broke the type constraint
```

The only exception is initializing variables or calling functions with object literals like here:

```
let b3: B = { a: 123, b: "abc", 0: { a: 123} } // Error since object literals are checked for excess properties.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEFYF5YG9YHICGGBcsA7AVwFsAjaAJ1gF8wo4AhZNWAbQA9YBLAw0ipQC6%20RDQDcIADbRQsMgEZ8zFKhqwsAZ1ZZ8CgEwBmADTz8AIixkAxudMAGfOl2wDh9eoD0n2KAD2oFhSUuCwAGa80MAycmT6yixqGtrOekamZBZWtg4Wbua0sN6wAKKUlH6U%20ADucGQVANZwoAAWzQyw1n4EmqCUWLyg0rLyhgmqGmkmZrCWNnawjjpTHkU%20ZRVVsH5kAFbQ1nJS3KBUQdpYlHC93MGdbdZNACZAA)

Comment: "type B means every number-property will have the type A". this is subtle indeed. Thanks.
PS: you said "yet another", do you have links to other examples ?